# Beautiful Soup : Can we generate the same output using Beautiful Soup like we generate using Selenium?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to web scrape the URL("https://asc.gov/appraiser") using BeautifulSoup in python. I have tried using Selenium but found Selenium has more complex and not user-friendly. I want to navigate the URL as 'website->Quick Search->Apply->Download' and point the 'download' output (300k result) to a specific directory in excel.  Can anyone help to generate it using BeautifulSoup? The below code is written on Selenium which can help to understand the path and arguments.

```
 from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
 from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
 from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
 import os
 from selenium import webdriver
 import time

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {'download.default_directory': download_path, 'download.prompt_for_download': False,
'download.directory_upgrade': True,
'safebrowsing.enabled': True}
options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driverLocation, options=options)
driver.get('https://asc.gov/appraiser')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

#Below line clicks Apply button
apply_button = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//span[text()="Apply"]')))
apply_button.click()

#Below line clicks Download button
download_button = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//a[text()="Download"]')))
download_button.click()

#Below line clicks on excel radio button
excel_radio = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'excel')))
excel_radio.click()

#Below line clicks Download button
download_button_2 = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'download')))
download_button_2.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `beautifulsoup` or `selenium` to download the tab-delimited CSV. `requests` with the right payload is enough:

```py
import requests

api_url = 'https://bridge.asc.gov/appraiser/query'

payload = {
    "output_xml": "<OUTPUT><FIELD name=\"license_state_abbr\" /><FIELD name=\"license_no\" /><FIELD name=\"first_name\" /><FIELD name=\"middle_name\" /><FIELD name=\"last_name\" /><FIELD name=\"suffix\" /><FIELD name=\"license_eff_date\" /><FIELD name=\"license_expir_date\" /><FIELD name=\"license_type\" /><FIELD name=\"license_status\" /><FIELD name=\"company_name\" /><FIELD name=\"phone_no\" /><FIELD name=\"street\" /><FIELD name=\"city\" /><FIELD name=\"state_abbr\" /><FIELD name=\"county\" /><FIELD name=\"zip\" /><FIELD name=\"aqb_passed\" /><FIELD name=\"disciplinary_action\" /><FIELD name=\"disciplinary_action_eff_date\" /><FIELD name=\"disciplinary_action_end_date\" /></OUTPUT>",
    "public_discipline_only": "1",
    "search_xml": "\"<SEARCH></SEARCH>\""
}

print('Downloading...', end='')

with open('asc_data.xls', 'wb') as f_out:
    f_out.write(requests.post(api_url, json=payload).content)

print('Done.')
```

Downloads `asc_data.xls` (screenshot from LibreOffice):

[image]

Comment: Where the data is downloaded. Can we point to any local directory?

Comment: @AKS Of course, you can change the path in the `open()` call.

Comment: Your answer is great but wants to know how you get into this one 'https://bridge.asc.gov/appraiser/query'. Is the API listed anywhere ? And can 'requests' works like a replacement for BeautifulSoup or Selenium? Please enlighten.

Comment: @AKS You can open in Firefox/Chrome web developer tools -> network tab and watch which API the page calls when you click Download button. I found the URL there.

Comment: But this answer seems shortcut. Just expecting the output using the BeautifulSoup library as a robust method. Let me know if you have such a way.